# How to check if a file is checked out (Clearcase / Python)

Tags: python, clearcase, python-2.4

I guess the title sufficiently sums up my question. I have working code to automatically check out a file:

```
 p = Popen(['cleartool', 'co', pathname], stdin = PIPE)
 p.communicate('comment for checkout')
```

I'm wondering how to check if the file is already checked out before executing this. Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the output of a `cleartool ls -short pathname`

If checked out, its version will end with `/CHECKEDOUT`.

Or you can go ahead, try to check out and test the exit status of the command. But there could be other causes for failure (other than "already checked out")

Comment: @Jon Grat! Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. Also, what code did you use to test the cleartool ls output?